# PyCuda: Dereferencing Array Element Via Pointer in Cuda Kernel

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cuda, pycuda

I am using PyCuda to pass pairs of arrays to a cuda kernel via a pointer. The arrays are the output of a different kernel, so the data is already on the GPU.

Within the kernel, I'm trying to access elements in each of the arrays to do a vector subtraction. The values that I'm getting for the elements in the array are not correct (h & p are wrong in the code below).

Can anyone help me see what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
from pycuda.tools import DeviceMemoryPool as DMP
from scipy.spatial import distance
import os
import glob

def get_cuda_hist_kernel():
        #Make the kernel
    histogram_kernel = """
    __global__ void kernel_getHist(unsigned int* array,unsigned int size, unsigned int* histo, float bucket_size, unsigned int num_bins, unsigned int* out_max)
    {
        unsigned int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
        if(x<size){
            unsigned int value = array[x];

            unsigned int bin = floor(float(value) * bucket_size) - 1;


            //Faster Modulo 3 for channel assignment
            unsigned int offset = x;
            offset = (offset >> 16) + (offset & 0xFFFF); 
            offset = (offset >>  8) + (offset & 0xFF);   
            offset = (offset >>  4) + (offset & 0xF);    
            offset = (offset >>  2) + (offset & 0x3);    
            offset = (offset >>  2) + (offset & 0x3);    
            offset = (offset >>  2) + (offset & 0x3);    
            if (offset > 2) offset = offset - 3;
            offset = offset * num_bins;

            bin += offset;

            atomicAdd(&histo[bin + offset],1);
        }
    }


    __global__ void kernel_chebyshev(unsigned int* histo, unsigned int* prev_histo, unsigned int number, int* output)
    {

        const unsigned int size = 12;
        //Get all of the differences
        __shared__ int temp_diffs[size];
        unsigned int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

        if (i < size){
            unsigned int diff = 0;
            unsigned int h = histo[i];
            unsigned int p = prev_histo[i];

            if (h > p)
            {
                diff = h - p;
            }
            else
            {
                diff = p - h;
            }
            temp_diffs[i] = (int)diff;
        }

        __syncthreads();

        output[number] = 0;
        atomicMax(&output[number], temp_diffs[i]);
    }
    """

    mod = SourceModule(histogram_kernel)
    return mod


def cuda_histogram(ims, block_size, kernel):

    start = time.time()
    max_val = 4
    num_bins = np.uint32(4)
    num_channels = np.uint32(3)
    bin_size = np.float32(1 / np.uint32(max_val / num_bins))

    #Memory Pool
    pool = DMP()
    print 'Pool Held Blocks: ', pool.held_blocks

    #Compute block & Grid dimensions

    bdim = (block_size, 1, 1)
    cols = ims[0].size
    rows = 1
    channels = 1

    dx, mx = divmod(cols, bdim[0])
    dy, my = divmod(rows, bdim[1])
    dz, mz = divmod(channels, bdim[2])
    g_x = (dx + (mx>0)) * bdim[0]
    g_y = (dy + (my>0)) * bdim[1]
    g_z = (dz + (mz>0)) * bdim[2]
    gdim = (g_x, g_y, g_z)

    #get the function
    func = kernel.get_function('kernel_getHist')
    func2 = kernel.get_function('kernel_chebyshev')

    #build list of histograms
    #send the histogram to the gpu
    hists = []
    device_hists = []
    for im in range(len(ims)):
        hists.append(np.zeros([num_channels * num_bins]).astype(np.uint32))

    end = time.time()
    dur = end - start
    print(' '.join(['Prep Time: ', str(dur)]))

    start = time.time()


    #Copy all of the image data to GPU
    device_images = []
    for im in range(len(ims)):
        #print('Allocating data for image :', im)
        #convert the image to 1D array of uint32s
        a = ims[im].astype(np.uint32)
        a = a.flatten('C')
        a_size = np.uint32(a.size)

        #allocate & send im data to gpu
        device_images.append(pool.allocate(a.nbytes))
        cuda.memcpy_htod(device_images[im], a)

        d_hist = pool.allocate(hists[im].nbytes)
        device_hists.append(d_hist)
        cuda.memcpy_htod(d_hist, hists[im])


    differences = np.zeros(len(ims)).astype(np.uint32)
    device_diffs = pool.allocate(differences.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(device_diffs, differences)


    for im in range(len(ims)):
        #run histogram function
        func(device_images[im], a_size, device_hists[im], bin_size, num_bins, block=(block_size,1,1), grid=gdim)

    cuda.Context.synchronize()
    device_hist_size = np.uint32(len(device_hists[im]))
    for im in range(1, len(ims)):
        number = np.uint32(im - 1)
        func2(device_hists[im], device_hists[im - 1], number, device_diffs, block=(32,1,1))

    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(differences, device_diffs)
    print(differences)

    for im in range(len(ims)):
        #get histogram back
        cuda.memcpy_dtoh(hists[im], device_hists[im])
        device_hists[im] = 0


    end = time.time()
    dur = end - start
    print(' '.join(['Load, Compute, & Gather Time: ', str(dur)]))
    pool.free_held()
    return differences

def get_all_files(directory):
    pattern = os.path.join(directory, '*.jpg')
    files = [f for f in glob.glob(pattern)]
    return files
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RESOURCES_PATH = "../data/ims/"
    MAX_IMS = 1000
    direc = os.path.join(RESOURCES_PATH, '21JumpStreet', 'source_video_frames')
    files = get_all_files(direc)
    a = cv2.imread('t.png')
    ims = [cv2.imread(f) for f in files]
    print 'Shape of my image: ', ims[0].shape
    print 'Number of images to histogram: ', len(ims)
    block_size = 128
    kernel = get_cuda_hist_kernel()
    start = time.time()

    num_diffs = len(ims) // MAX_IMS + 1
    cuda_diffs = []

    for i in range(num_diffs):

        first = i * MAX_IMS
        last = (i + 1) * MAX_IMS
        print(first)
        small_set = ims[first:last]
        print 'Small set size: ', str(len(small_set))
        cuda_diffs.extend(cuda_histogram(small_set, block_size, kernel))

    end = time.time()
    dur = end - start
    print(' '.join(['CUDA version took:', str(dur)]))

    start = time.time()
    cv_hists = []
    for i in range(len(ims)):
        im = ims[i % len(ims)]
        h = []
        for j in range(3):
            hist = cv2.calcHist([im], [j], None, [4], [0, 100])
            h.extend(hist)
        cv_hists.append(h)

    #run Chebyshev on CPU:
    color_hist_diffs = np.array([distance.chebyshev(cv_hists[i-1], cv_hists[i]) \
                                 for i in range(len(cv_hists)) if i != 0])
    print(color_hist_diffs)
    end = time.time()
    dur = end - start
    print(' '.join(['CPU & cv2 version took:', str(dur)]))
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly Added the rest of my code... might be too much detail. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing that! You wouldn't believe how many people I've asked to update their question, so I can try to help them, and it never happens. That is a lot of code though, I can see why you didn't post it in full : )

Comment: Have you checked that the arrays used in `kernel_chebyshev`, which are the output of a different kernel, are correct?

Comment: You have posted over 200 LOC, and yet the example still isn't really useable because of all the external dependencies and image file requirements. [SO] isn't a free debugging and mistake spotting service, please don't treat it like one. If you can create a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe exactly what is the problem you are having, someone might be able to help you. But not with the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I didn't want to upload all of the code, because I don't intend to use Stack Overflow as a debugging service. Thank you for the link MCVE link, that is quite helpful both for my future Stack Overflow questions and also for my personal coding & debugging practices.

When I created an MCVE, I confirmed that my kernel was working fine; my problem was an error elsewhere in my code that was messing up the bin counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bad question, as the error was elsewhere in my code. Sorry for the confusion.